# Program crashing after using scanf

Tags: c, scanf

This is a program I wrote that calculates time of landing a plane when you give it starting time and it flies for a second. But when I run a program and insert the first number in the console it immediately crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int m, s;
    int u;
    long flight, landing;

    printf("insert time of taking a plane:\n time in hours: "); 
    scanf("%d, &u");
    printf(" minutes: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf(" seconds: ");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    printf("Duration of a flight (in seconds): ");
    scanf("%ld", &flight);
    pristanek = u * 3600 + m * 60 + s + let;
    u = landing / 3600;
    m = (landing % 3600) % 60;
    s = landing % 60;
    printf("Time of landing; %d:%02d:%02d\n", u, m, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is due to the fact that the correct syntax for `scanf` is:

```
scanf("%d", &u); // notice the " is after the "d"
```

You actually got it right in your other `scanf`s.